# Are these two context free grammar rules the same?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Is there a difference between these two grammar definitions (where `|` denotes OR and `;` is just a regular character)?

```
1. <foo> ::= <bar> | <foo> ; <bar>
2. <foo> ::= <bar> | <bar> ; <foo>
```

It seems to me that foo would match a sequence that looks like `<bar> ; <bar> ; <bar> ; ....` regardless of which definition is used.  Am I missing something here or are they functionally the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree that they're equivalent, since the end result of both is one or more `<bar>`'s. But if any new rules were added to `<foo>` (such rules involving terminals or non-terminals other than `<bar>`), they probably wouldn't be equivalent anymore.